# Find/Replace using grep and Textwrangler

Tags: regex, grep

I'm using `grep` on TextWrangler to find strings of this type:

```
4,600.00
```

My regex command is the following:

```
\d.\d{3}.\d{2}
```

which seems to find the strings correctly. I would like to replace the string `4,600.00` with `4600.00` as I wish to save the data in a `.csv` file. How do I remove the comma from each number that I find?

Comment: i guess your line contains not only this number but something like"foo,bar,blah,4,600,000.00,some,more"  however, what if the line is "foo,bar,blah,999,600,000.00,..." how can you say 999 and 600000.00 are two columns? are there other rule in your input file?

Comment: The numbers stay below 100,000 so I only need to find `,000.00`. I'm unclear what the replacement code is though; I tried `\d\d{3}.\d{2}
`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Search: `(\d{1,3}),(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,2})`

Replace: `\1\2.\3`

Works in TextWrangler.

Answer (score 1):

awk oneliner:

```
awk  --re-interval  '{x=gensub(/([0-9]{1,3}),([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})/,"\\1\\2","g");print x}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  awk --version|head -1
GNU Awk 3.1.6

kent$  echo "foo,bar,blah,46,000.00,some,more"|awk --re-interval  '{x=gensub(/([0-9]{1,3}),([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})/,"\\1\\2","g");print x}'
foo,bar,blah,46000.00,some,more
```

Comment: the real question here was for TextWrangler, not for command line

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,3}),([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})/\1\2/g' file.txt
```

You could add the `-i` flag to write the changes directly to the file.